# MSAL - MsalGuard on Redirect URI - getting into redirect loop

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, adal, msal.js, msal-angular

I'm implementing `msal` in my angular application and I'm using `msal-v1` library.

I have taken `angular-7` sample from the documented samples and tried implementing the below code in my enterprise application.

I have added `popup as false` in app.module.ts

```
MsalModule.forRoot(
      {
        auth: {
          clientId: "app client id",
          authority:
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/",
          validateAuthority: true,
          redirectUri: window.location.origin,
          postLogoutRedirectUri:
            window.location.origin,
          navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: "localStorage",
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
        },
      },
      {
        popUp: false,
        consentScopes: ["user.read", "openid", "profile"],
        unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
        protectedResourceMap,
        extraQueryParameters: {},
      }
    )
```

and on app-routing.module.ts, I have added `MsalGuard on the empty route` as my application wont have any login button and the default landing page also needs authentication.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
  },
  {
    path: "profile",
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

By doing this, if I directly hit the domain URL(i.e. redirect URI) with out any route, I was able to authorize and get token properly in the localstorage, but if we clear local storage and then directly navigate to profile path, I was not able to get the token as it is entering a continuously `redirect loop`.

the application is redirecting to /#id_token=eyJ and then to /profile/#id_token=eyJ and so on.

please guide me on how to guard all routes in my angular application and not enter the redirect loop.

```
msal version - 1.4.4
msal-angular - 1.1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discussed the same issue in the github(`msal-v1`) forum and have found a alternate solution by setting a new route without the `MsalGuard` but to the same `HomeComponent`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth-redirect',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  }
];
```

full details are discussed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4614)

Comment: but doesn't this let the user go straight to the home component without authenticating by entering <root>/auth-redirect to the URL?

Comment: yes, there is a little delay while navigating through pages to reach to home component.